# Would someone give an explanation of this PHP switch block?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'd like to ask what this code is doing, and if someone could explain to me with comments?

I am trying to understand what it is doing. I am guessing it switches between them depending on the result of the statements E.g. 2 < 1 and 2 > 1. Then it is setting the dates in a year month day format?

Am I on the right track?

```
switch (true) {
    case ($UserBirthday < $CurrentDate2) :
        $CurrentDate->setDate($UserBirthday->format('Y'), $CurrentDate->format('m'), $CurrentDate->format('d'));
        break;

    case ($CurrentDate2 < $UserBirthday) :
        $UserBirthday->setDate($CurrentDate->format('Y'), $UserBirthday->format('m'), $UserBirthday->format('d'));
        break;
}

$interval = $UserBirthday->diff($CurrentDate);
$difference = $interval->format('%R%a')-1;
```

Also, can I change it to an if/else statement like this?

```
    if ($UserBirthday < $CurrentDate2) {
        $CurrentDate->setDate($UserBirthday->format('Y'), $CurrentDate->format('m'), $CurrentDate->format('d'));
        }

    else if ($CurrentDate2 < $UserBirthday) {
        $UserBirthday->setDate($CurrentDate->format('Y'), $UserBirthday->format('m'), $UserBirthday->format('d'));
       }


$interval = $UserBirthday->diff($CurrentDate);
$difference = $interval->format('%R%a')-1;
```

Comment: `switch (true)`? That's... odd. That's quite an oddly structured piece of code - basically it's a bastardised if/else statement. The first `case` that evaulates to `true` will be executed.

Comment: I thought it was just like an if/else statement.  ? Although I haven't used switch statements that much. I found the structure somewhere online, but now cant locate it to further understand it.

Comment: are you just getting the days from birthday? why not just get the month, then if that date is less adjust it to the next year then make the difference

Comment: Birthday is holding the birthday is a format like 21-04-87
I could do it that way I suppose, Im not really sure what I have done haha

Comment: Yeah, you should just use an `if/else` statement here since it serves what you are trying to achieve in a far more straightforward and readable manner. A `switch` statement is subtly different - you can read about it in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to get an idea of its use cases. The `if/else` you posted is fine, but bear in mind that it does not cover the condition where both dates are equal. Have a think about whether this is necessary for your specific case or not.

Comment: Ah thats a very good point. When I changed the users birthday to the current date I had issues, but have resolved it by creating an if statement to check if its the same as the current date. I think thats what you mean?

Comment: Well, it all depends on what you want your application to do ;) The question that you should ask yourself is, what conditions are likely to happen, and _which_ ones do I care about? For instance, when comparing two values, you might specifically care if `a > b`  else if `a == b` else if `a < b`. In other words, you want one of three things to happen. Sometimes, you just might want one of two things to happen; e.g: if `a >= b` do something, otherwise, do something else. Either way, it's important think about and identify each possibility and ensure your logic covers it to avoid possible bugs :)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the help Darragh! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there doesn't appear to be any benefit from using `switch` over `if..elseif..else` statements in your code example, switch is often used in place of long, ugly `if..elseif..elseif..elseif..etc.` statements. I suspect this is what the author of your code example was modeling.

You can read about switch's many uses at http://phpswitch.com/.

Comment: I understand what you mean. In my case it does not require that many statements, therefore if/else could work fine over the switch. Thanks for that Ben!

Comment: @MitchellB You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've changed my mind, there is nothing wrong with this code, albeit maybe a bit confusing.

Normally you would pass a variable into the switch statement and compare its values in the cases:

```
switch($a) {
    case 1:
    // some code
    break;
}
```

In this case, they are basically only checking if something is true, so they pass true into the switch and then each case is a logic statement.

Either way, whatever is passed into the switch is compared with a == against what is in each case. Since switch is useful for large sets of if/else it is valid to use in this case if they wanted to.

However, since they used it in a way that most developers may not be familiar with, it can be confusing and some additional commenting might be wise.

But again, I was wrong, there actually isn't anything wrong with this code.

Comment: I understand what you mean about it not being best practise. Thanks for the  answer though. I think I will just change it to an if/else statement. It makes more sense to me.
Thanks :-)

Comment: My answer was unclear, using the switch is not best practice, I'll update it

Comment: Makes sense to me! Thanks for the update Asperon.
Although its funny, I deleted the if/else statements and the switch and just left the two lines to change the formats of them, and it works fine. I honestly have no idea why I had to check with the control structures, because I now imagine that it would not have mattered..
Many thanks,

Comment: @Asperon I think I'll have to respectfully disagree with your updated answer ;) In your original answer you asserted that using a switch statement in this manner was not best practice. I agree 100% with this, for several reasons. Most importantly in my view, since code is written once and read often, it's important that code be understandable. Using a `switch` statement in this manner (comparing a literal value, and then performing object comparison in the `case` clauses) obscures the intent of this operation - which can be clearly expressed as an `if/elseif/else` condition.

Comment: Technically, the statement does the job. But at the expense of readability. Additionally, there could be unforeseen pitfalls in this approach. A future developer might be required to modify this code, perhaps adding another case - were they to accidentally exclude a `break` you could see a fall-through to another condition that evaluates to `true`. An opportunity for subtle bugs. This is not an explicit concern with an `if/else/elseif` statement, which guarantees execution of code in the first condition that evaluates to true only.

Comment: I may need to update my answer, because I agree with the readability issue.